# Get database table data older then 10 days in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-views

I am trying to retrieve data older then 10 days to update that field data. Currently my model is like

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My database table is

[image: data creation dates]

Now when I query the database:

```
dish = Restaurant.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10))
```

I get the whole table's data. I even tried to change from a day to 1 day. It still is a full database result.

Comment: I believe that query is finding records _newer_ than 10 days old, not _older_.  Try using `timestamp__lt` instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon  its returning nothing even when I do last 2 days or 1 day data.

Comment: None of those timestamps are a day (24 hours) old yet.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes got where I was wrong thanks for pointing though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely just a mistake. Try `timestamp__lt` for *older* results. `timestamp__gt` is recording records for newer results. I asked you to try 1 minute for `gt`, and it worked. That should display the whole database because all of these are older than 1 min. And also, as said, Django recommends `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`. So you made a error, why `timestamp__lt` returns the whole database for 10 days is because all posts are less than 10 days old. But `lt` returns nothing for 1 minute because all of the data is older than 1 minute.

Comment: So According to my logic I will get data of that resturants which are 10 days old just . not even 9 days and 23 hours ?  Am I right ?

Comment: Yep. So 9 days and 23 hours does *not* count as 10 days.

Answer (score 8):

If you want data that is **older** then you probably need to use `__lt` instead of `__gt`.

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone as tz
d = tz.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)

dish = Restaurant.objects.filter(timestamp__lt=d)
```

Django recomends using [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) instead of `datetime.now()` to make sure that the timezone info is correct.

Comment: returning non . even I did 2 . In which all data should come ? As per my database entries . but nothing is appearing

Comment: All of the timestamps in your question are from yesterday or today.  Do you have more data you didn't show us, that actually is ten days old?

Comment: @gamer that's because you said it returns the whole table so as I can see, there are no results older than 10 days old.

Comment: @zixuan  but when I post 1 day or 2 even I put from 1 to 10 . still no result was show. data in database is 2 days older. Why I am unable to access it ?

Comment: The oldest timestamp shown in the question is yesterday at 9:30 pm.  That timestamp is not yet a day old.

Comment: @gamer be careful. What about 1 minute?

Comment: @zixuan  yes whole database is appearing

Comment: @gamer do you mean for `lt` or `gt`?

Comment: @zixuan  using lt.

Comment: @zixuan  I think issue was __lt . as you both pointed . As data is 23 hours old when  
 I get all data. maybe its accurate answer ? As I want data of resturant which are not approved from last 10 days . so I want data of that resurants. not even 9 days 23 hours.

Comment: 9 days and 23 hours does *not* count as 10 days @gamer.